# Haskell Network.Browser HTTPS Connection

Tags: networking, haskell, https

Is there a way to make https calls with the Network.Browser package.
I'm not seeing it in the [documentation on Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/HTTP/4000.0.9/doc/html/Network-Browser.html).
If there isn't a way to do it with browse is there another way to fetch https pages?

My current test code is

```
import Network.HTTP
import Network.URI (parseURI)
import Network.HTTP.Proxy
import Data.Maybe (fromJust)
import Control.Applicative ((<$>))
import Network.Browser

retrieveUrl :: String -> IO String
retrieveUrl url = do
  rsp <- browse $ request (Request (fromJust uri) POST [] "Body")
  return $ snd (rspBody <$> rsp)
  where uri = parseURI url
```

I've been running **nc -l -p 8000** and watching the output. 
I see that it doesn't encrypt it when I do **retrieveUrl https://localhost:8000**

Also when I try a real https site I get:

```
Network.Browser.request: Error raised ErrorClosed
*** Exception: user error (Network.Browser.request: Error raised ErrorClosed)
```

Edit: Network.Curl solution (For doing a SOAP call)

```
import Network.Curl (curlGetString)
import Network.Curl.Opts

soapHeader s = CurlHttpHeaders ["Content-Type: text/xml", "SOAPAction: " ++ s]
proxy        = CurlProxy "proxy.foo.org"
envelope     = "myRequestEnvelope.xml"

headers  = readFile envelope >>= (\x -> return [ soapHeader "myAction"
                                               , proxy
                                               , CurlPost True
                                               , CurlPostFields [x]]) 

main = headers >>= curlGetString "https://service.endpoint"
```

Comment: You should not have accepted that answer; since SO is for the benefit of everyone - having an open question would have stimulated more answers (or even development).

Comment: @drozzy still worth answering even if an answer has been excepted. http-conduit is a newer package and seems to be a more convenient answer to the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've wondered about this in the past and have always ended up just using the [libcurl bindings](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/curl). It would be nice to have a more Haskelly solution, but `Network.Curl` is very convenient.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up going with Network.Curl based on your suggestion, thanks for the help.

Comment: @AlexKahn I believe that's correct (still, in 2013). There's a little mention in one of the modules I just noticed

Answer (score 12):

An alternative and perhaps more "haskelly" solution as Travis Brown put it with http-conduit:

To just fetch https pages:

```
import Network.HTTP.Conduit
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as L

main = simpleHttp "https://www.noisebridge.net/wiki/Noisebridge" >>= L.putStr
```

The below shows how to pass urlencode parameters.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Network.HTTP.Conduit
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as L

main = do
  initReq <- parseUrl "https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url"
  let req' = initReq { secure = True } -- Turn on https
  let req = (flip urlEncodedBody) req' $
             [ ("longUrl", "http://www.google.com/")
--             ,
             ]
  response <- withManager $ httpLbs req
  L.putStr $ responseBody response
```

You can also set the method, content-type, and request body manually. The api is the same as in http-enumerator a good example is: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5614946

Answer (score 3):

If all you want to do is fetch a page, [Network.HTTP.Wget](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/http-wget/0.6.2/doc/html/Network-HTTP-Wget.html) is the most simple way.  Exhibit a:

```
import Network.HTTP.Wget

main = putStrLn =<< wget "https://www.google.com" [] []
```