# Downloading from HTTPS

Tags: haskell, https

I'll keep it simple:
I'd like to download a file via HTTPS; methods I've tried haven't worked (Network.HTTP.Wget, Network.Curl, Network.Download).
Suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: This is a bad question. You need to explain why they haven't worked! I've had great success with both curl and wget.

Answer (score 6):

See the [http-enumerator](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-enumerator-0.6.5.6), it works with SSL as well as enumerator/iteratee IO (with the enumerator package). Hence you can pipe it into attoparsec via attoparsec-iterator and efficiently parse the data.

Comment: Cool package, at present, is listed as deprecated in favor of http-conduit.

Answer (score 3):

This question comes up every [once in a while](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13465740/128583):

The solution I use currently is:

```
import Network.HTTP.Conduit
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as L

main = simpleHttp "https://www.noisebridge.net/wiki/Noisebridge" >>= L.putStr
```

There is also an explanation of how to post with http-conduit in the link as well as a few answers with other methods.

Comment: Holy mother does http-conduit ever have a lot of deps.