# Resolving Network.HTTP 'user error (https not supported)'

Tags: haskell, https

When running this Haskell program using `runghc`:

```
import Network.HTTP

main = simpleHTTP (getRequest "https://stackoverflow.com")
       >>= getResponseBody >>= putStrLn
```

I get the error message

```
printso.hs: user error (https not supported)
```

I don't want to switch to unencrypted HTTP -- how can I use [`Network.HTTP`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HTTP-4000.0.8/docs/Network-HTTP.html) with SSL/TLS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do that directly, see for example [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988115/haskell-network-browser-https-connection). However you could use [`Network.HTTP.Conduit`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-conduit-2.0.0.3/docs/Network-HTTP-Conduit.html) from the `http-conduit` library instead.

First install it using `cabal install http-conduit`.

Then you can use this code (note that it contrast to `Network.HTTP` it uses lazy `ByteString`s) as a replacement:

```
import Network.HTTP.Conduit
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as LB

main = simpleHttp "https://stackoverflow.com"
       >>= LB.putStr
```

Another alternative is to use [the Haskell *libcurl* binding](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/curl) which depends on the native [*libcurl*](http://curl.haxx.se/), however.

Comment: can you suggest how can I put filter on this stream. I want to find some text from this String...

Comment: @Manvi I think you could use conduit's `sink` to get an `IO Text` or something like that, and then use standard filters for `String` or `Text`, see  e.g. this tutorial: https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/school/to-infinity-and-beyond/pick-of-the-week/conduit-overview